# Bluetooth project,when bluetooth is disconnected or out of range

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino-uno

I am trying to program that will display a notification when bluetooth device (arduino uno)disconnected or out of range.
When i testing ,power off the bluetooth device,phone has delay 20s show the notificatoin.

I don't know why,hope somebody help me figure it out.

```js
package com.example.arduinosensors;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.UUID;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button btnOn, btnOff;
    TextView txtArduino, txtString, txtStringLength, sensorView0, sensorView1, sensorView2, sensorView3;
    Handler bluetoothIn;

    public static final int handlerState = 0,MESSAGE_LOST_CONNECT = 1;     //used to identify handler message
    private BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = null;
    private BluetoothSocket btSocket = null;
    private StringBuilder recDataString = new StringBuilder();
    private Vibrator mVibrator;
    private ConnectedThread mConnectedThread;

    // SPP UUID service - this should work for most devices
    private static final UUID BTMODULEUUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

    // Insert your bluetooth devices MAC address
    private static String address = "20:14:12:03:11:31";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Link the buttons and textViews to respective views
        btnOn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonOn);
        btnOff = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonOff);
        txtString = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtString);
        txtStringLength = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.testView1);
        sensorView0 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sensorView0);
        sensorView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sensorView1);
        sensorView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sensorView2);
        sensorView3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sensorView3);

        mVibrator=(Vibrator) getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

        bluetoothIn = new Handler() {
            public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
                if (msg.what == handlerState) {                  //if message is what we want
                    String readMessage = (String) msg.obj;                                  // msg.arg1 = bytes from connect thread
                    recDataString.append(readMessage);              //keep appending to string until ~
                    int endOfLineIndex = recDataString.indexOf("~");                        // determine the end-of-line
                    if (endOfLineIndex > 0) {                                               // make sure there data before ~
                        String dataInPrint = recDataString.substring(0, endOfLineIndex);    // extract string
                        txtString.setText("Data Received = " + dataInPrint);
                        int dataLength = dataInPrint.length();           //get length of data received
                        txtStringLength.setText("String Length = " + String.valueOf(dataLength));

                        if (recDataString.charAt(0) == '#')            //if it starts with # we know it is what we are looking for
                        {
                            String sensor0 = recDataString.substring(1, 5);                 //get sensor value from string between indices 1-5
                            String sensor1 = recDataString.substring(6, 10);                //same again...
                            String sensor2 = recDataString.substring(11, 15);
                            String sensor3 = recDataString.substring(16, 20);

                            sensorView0.setText(" Sensor 0 Voltage = " + sensor0 + "V"); //update the textviews with sensor values
                            sensorView1.setText(" Sensor 1 Voltage = " + sensor1 + "V");
                            sensorView2.setText(" Sensor 2 Voltage = " + sensor2 + "V");
                            sensorView3.setText(" Sensor 3 Voltage = " + sensor3 + "V");
                        }
                            recDataString.delete(0, recDataString.length());      //clear all string data
                    }
                }
                if(msg.what == MESSAGE_LOST_CONNECT) {    //
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    mVibrator.vibrate(new long[]{10, 100, 100, 100}, -1);
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                            .setTitle("bluetooth disconnected")
                            .setIcon(R.drawable.blue1)
                            .setMessage("bluetooth out of range")
                            .setPositiveButton("yes", new
                                    DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i)
                                        {
                                            //finish();
                                        }
                                    })
                            .setNegativeButton("cancel", new
                                    DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i)
                                        {

                                        }
                                    })
                                    .show();
                                    }
            }
             
        };

        btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();       // get Bluetooth adapter
        checkBTState();

        btnOff.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mConnectedThread.write("0");    // Send "0" via Bluetooth
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Turn off LED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        btnOn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mConnectedThread.write("1");    // Send "1" via Bluetooth
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Turn on LED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    private BluetoothSocket createBluetoothSocket(BluetoothDevice device) throws IOException {

        return  device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(BTMODULEUUID);
        //creates secure outgoing connecetion with BT device using UUID
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        //Get MAC address from DeviceListActivity via intent
        Intent intent = getIntent();

        //Get the MAC address from the DeviceListActivty via EXTRA
        //address = intent.getStringExtra(DeviceListActivity.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS);

        //create device and set the MAC address
        BluetoothDevice device = btAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);

        try {
            btSocket = createBluetoothSocket(device);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Socket creation failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        // Establish the Bluetooth socket connection.
        try
        {
            btSocket.connect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            try
            {
                btSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e2)
            {
                //insert code to deal with this
            }
        }
        mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(btSocket);
        mConnectedThread.start();

        //I send a character when resuming.beginning transmission to check device is connected
        //If it is not an exception will be thrown in the write method and finish() will be called
        mConnectedThread.write("x");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
        try
        {
            //Don't leave Bluetooth sockets open when leaving activity
            btSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e2) {
            //insert code to deal with this
        }
    }

    //Checks that the Android device Bluetooth is available and prompts to be turned on if off
    private void checkBTState() {

        if(btAdapter==null) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "裝置並不支援藍芽", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            if (btAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            } else {
                Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, 1);

            }
        }
    }

    //create new class for connect thread
    private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
        private final InputStream mmInStream;
        private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

        //creation of the connect thread
        public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            OutputStream tmpOut = null;

            try {
                //Create I/O streams for connection
                tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
                tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) { }

            mmInStream = tmpIn;
            mmOutStream = tmpOut;
        }

        private void connectionLost() {   //斷線通知副程式
           // Send a failure message back to the Activity
           Message msg = bluetoothIn.obtainMessage(MainActivity.MESSAGE_LOST_CONNECT);
           bluetoothIn.sendMessage(msg);
        }

        public void run() {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
            int bytes;
            // Keep looping to listen for received messages
            while (true) {
                try {
                    bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);            //read bytes from input buffer
                    String readMessage = new String(buffer, 0, bytes);
                    // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity via handler
                    bluetoothIn.obtainMessage(handlerState, bytes, -1, readMessage).sendToTarget();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    connectionLost();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        //write method
        public void write(String input) {
            byte[] msgBuffer = input.getBytes();           //converts entered String into bytes
            try {
                mmOutStream.write(msgBuffer);                //write bytes over BT connection via outstream
            } catch (IOException e) {
                //if you cannot write, close the application
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "連線失敗", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();

            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22200364/android-detect-bluetooth-disconnect-immediately-max-2-seconds